# Get Values From PHP array and showing them

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I'm doing a crud named FUND, where I can store many things along with a array using PHP *implode* method. In that array i'm storing some FUND Id. 
Here is array Create Code:

```
<div class="custom-checkbox">
  <label for="receive[]">Select Receive Funds</label>
    @foreach($funds as $fund)
     <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
       <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" name="receive[]" id="{{$fund->id}}" value="{{$fund->id}}">
        <label for="{{$fund->id}}"  class="custom-control-label">{{$fund->title}}</label>
     </div>
   @endforeach
```

Here is the store code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title'=>'required',
        'image'=>'required',
        'description',
        'available'=>'required',
        'buy'=>'required',
        'account',
        'receive',
    ]);
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move(public_path('funds'), $new_name);
    $form_data = array(
        'title'=>$request->title,
        'image'=>$new_name,
        'description'=>$request->description,
        'available'=>$request->available,
        'buy'=>$request->buy,
        'buyrate'=>$request->buyrate,
        'sellrate'=>$request->sellrate,
        'account'=>$request->account,
        'receive'=>implode(',', (array)($request->receive)),
    );

    Fund::create($form_data);

    return redirect('/admin/fund');
}
```

I'm showing that array on my index page using PHP *explode* method.

```
$receive=[];
foreach($funds as $fund){
    $receive = explode(",",$fund->receive);
}
```

As I mentioned I'm storing fund id in that array. So i want to show the whole row by using the Fund ID.For that I'm using query by this:

```
@foreach($receive as $r)
  <a href="/multi" class="list-group-item">
    <p>
      <img src="{{$fund=\App\Fund::where(['id'=>$r])->get('image')}}" width="32px" height="32px"> {{$fund=\App\Fund::where(['id'=>$r])->get('title')}}
        <span class="pull-right text text-muted hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="font-size:11px;">
          <small>Reserve: {{$fund=\App\Fund::where(['id'=>$r])->get('available')}}<br>Exchange rate: {{$fund=\App\Fund::where(['id'=>$r])->get('buyrate')}}</small>
        </span>
    </p>
  </a>
```

@endforeach

But the title image is showing like this 
[image: Frontend View]

**How Can I just Get Title, Image and other staff without any bracket?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several researches i fixed it. Here is the answer:

```
@php $receives = \App\Fund::whereIn('id', $receive)->get(); @endphp
   @foreach($receives as $r)
       <a href="/multi" class="list-group-item">
           <p>
              <img src="{{ $r->image_url  }}" width="32px" height="32px"> {{ $r->title  }}
                <span class="pull-right text text-muted hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="font-size:11px;">
                    <small>Reserve: {{ $r->available }}<br>Exchange rate: {{ $r->buyrate }}</small>
                 </span>
            </p>
         </a>
   @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of brackets try to use the tags  Like I do in the next example;

```
<img src="<?=$fund=\App\Fund::where(['id'=>$r])->get('image')?>"...
```

If the route to the image is good it should work.
If you have any other problem after this tell me :)